# NSSortDescriptor with two equally important keys

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

I am constructing a NSFetchedResultsController for my entity, which has two attributes, let's say a shortName and a longName. All of the managed objects only have either the shortName or the longName.

How can I sort the objects based on both attributes (or rather the one which is not null) at the same time?

Clearly the following will not work in my case:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"shortName" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"longName" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2, nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite interesting, but Im almost sure it is not possible to do. Just assigning shortName to the longName attribute, if there is no longName, while inserting to your db would be the best solution for me and simply sorting on longName.

Comment: thanks, that could be an option, however I believe that there should be a more elegant solution

Comment: Probably you can try to subclass NSFetchedResultsController, that would be elegant, but Im also curios if there is a simple solution to this